# How to set up django project with gunicorn service on gunicorn.socket?

Tags: django, service, gunicorn, wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm trying to run my django project on gunicorn socket as service. But it fails to start; Can anybody help me with this?

I tried by following this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04
I'm also using virtualenvwrapper to manage my virtualenvs.

Here is my configuration files:
/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mohsen
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/mohsen/Desktop/SummerCampDocs/carpooling/carpooling
ExecStart=/home/mohsen/.virtualenvs/carpooling/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock carpooling.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

By running this commands:

```sh
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

I get the following message:

```sh
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-08-28 12:38:18 +0430; 33min ago
  Process: 14000 ExecStart=/home/mohsen/.virtualenvs/carpooling/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock carpooling.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14000 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 gunicorn[14000]:     self.stop()
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 gunicorn[14000]:   File "/home/mohsen/.virtualenvs/carpooling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 gunicorn[14000]:     time.sleep(0.1)
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 gunicorn[14000]:   File "/home/mohsen/.virtualenvs/carpooling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 gunicorn[14000]:     self.reap_workers()
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 gunicorn[14000]:   File "/home/mohsen/.virtualenvs/carpooling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 gunicorn[14000]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 gunicorn[14000]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 28 12:38:18 mohsen-ThinkPad-T490 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: shouldn't you bind to gunicorn.socket rather than unix:/run/gunicorn.sock?

Comment: @dirkgroten I it this also, doesn't work!

Comment: If you django project gives an error at startup, that could also be a cause. Take a look at your Django log files. Maybe there's an error there.

Comment: @dirkgroten Django project has no error. I checked it.

Comment: Add a temporary `logging.error()` message to your **wsgi.py** just to check whether this file is reached at all.

Comment: @dirkgroten I checked; It fails in line ```application = get_wsgi_application()``` in wsgi.py file! Do you have any idea why?

Comment: then there must be an error log by Django. Where are you outputting your error logs (what is in your LOGGING settings?)

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't know what is the problem, but seems my log settings doesn't work correctly!

Comment: @dirkgroten I checked log using ```journalctl -f -u gunicorn``` and it is the same as I mentioned in my first question.

Comment: have a look at your general syslog. But in general, make sure your have LOGGING settings on production that log to a file using the `FileHandler` (or `WatchedFileHandler`) not the `StreamHandler`.